# How we can deal with large number of category present in a column around 300K. in Preprocessing Data?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, data-cleaning

I have the datasets in which a column has about 275 categories out of 9700 rows. Using get_dummies will get me many columns. Is doing this good practice.? or What other technique could be applied to deal with this.? (Here i have to determine the lowest price, company can fix to sell a product in market.)

```
df2['Market_Category'].nunique()
```

Output: **275**

Comment: What's the purpose of doing `get_dummies`? You should be able to select whatever you need keeping it as just a single column. IMO, `get_dummies` is really only needed if you require some specific output, or want to create features for a regression

Comment: What is your end goal?  What do you want the output dataframe or data to look like?

Comment: I want to reduce the categorical values in a column as their is many number of categories in a column and extract only some useful features that help my model (Linear Regression) to predict the price(targets) accurately.@ScottBoston,@ALollZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a good idea to have many columns, that will lead to problems in training. Read about [the Curse of Dimensionality](https://towardsdatascience.com/the-curse-of-dimensionality-50dc6e49aa1e).
To deal with this problem, you have some options:

1. First thing that I do, is to get the counts of each category:

```
df2['Market_Category'].value_counts()
```

If you have many categories that are repeated only few times (like some categories count less than 10 in 10000 samples), you can create a new category called *others* for them, instead of creating a columns for each. This will not affect the performance, since you are not losing that much information; and decrease the number of columns.

2. Next, If after the previous step, you still get a lot of columns (for example if all the categories count the same amount) you can use some techniques for dimentionality reduction, such as [PCA](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-one-stop-shop-for-principal-component-analysis-5582fb7e0a9c). What they do in simple words, is that they find the best columns to keep and discard the rest.

Hope I answered your question.